# F5 load balancer interaction

Tags: linux, bash, shell, f5

I want to run a `bash` script from my linux machine. It should connect to F5 Load balancer and run set of commands on the load balancer.

Working command used to connect F5:

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh username@f5hostname
```

**Bash script i tried:**

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p "password" ssh username@f5hostname

modify /ltm pool  poolA_8080 members modify { 10.32.76.21:8080 { session user-
disabled state user-down } }
```

If I run this script from my linux machine, it logs in to F5 but the 'modify' command is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this right, there is a new line character after `ssh`. Try following:

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p "password" ssh username@f5hostname \
"modify /ltm pool poolA_8080 members modify { 10.32.76.21:8080 { session user-disabled state user-down } }"
```

On a side note, storing passwords in scripts is not a good idea as they can easily leak. Better use a key-based ssh login.

Comment: Thanks smbear. I have made changes as per your suggestion then, It worked. I have modified to prompting the username&password.

Comment: Want to understand the usage of '\' after the sshpass command

Comment: `man bash`: "A non-quoted backslash (\\) is the escape character.  It  preserves  the literal value of the next character that follows, with the exception of <newline>.  If a \<newline> pair appears,  and  the  backslash  is  not itself  quoted,  the \<newline> is treated as a line continuation (that is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively ignored)."

Comment: i want to add one more line in the script, to disable one more server. If add "modify /ltm......." it's not executing this second line.